# Can't get Windows 8.1 to appear in loader list in GRUB

Tags: linux, boot, windows-8.1, debian, grub

I have a Dell laptop with Win 8.1 preinstalled and wanted to dual boot to Linux. So I partitioned off 100gb of the main and only hard drive and installed Kali Linux (Debian 7). It asked if I wanted to install GRUB boot loader to the MBR and I selected yes. All installations went smoothly.

The problem is that through GRUB, Kali and the Kali recovery are my only boot options; Windows 8 is not listed. Through GParted, I can see my Windows OS partition (`dev/sda5`).  I can even access it and look at files and folders, but I cant get it as a boot option in GRUB.

So now the only way to boot Windows 8 is to go to my BIOS boot settings and select UEFI boot - Windows Boot Manager.  If I want to run Kali, I power on as normal and let GRUB take over.

Can anyone help me with a step-by-step process to fix this? My Linux knowledge is practically 0. I'm not sure if the problem is related to EFI or what-have-you. The laptop is less than a year old.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about this mess, is to install Windows first, then install any Linux Distro afterwards.
You can look at this article if you intend to add it manually,https://askubuntu.com/questions/528947/how-to-add-windows-8-entry-to-grub-after-boot-repair
but the risk is if you mess it up you won't access either.

Comment: Windows WAS installed first, THEN he installed the Distro, so your link should actually be sufficient....:D